# Get the current <li> number

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a list like this one:

```
<ul>

  <li>
    <a href="..."> ... </a>
    <a href="..."> ... </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="..."> ... </a>
    <a href="..."> ... </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="..."> ... </a>
    <a href="..."> ... </a>
  </li>

  ...

</ul>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$("li").each(function(){
     // do stuff
});
```

How can I get the current list number (like 1, 2 or 3) inside that jquery function (where do stuff is)?

Comment: Looks like a trifecta!!  I was going to post my answer, but looks like I need to be a lot quicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback function passed to `each` has two arguments, the first being the index you're looking for:

```
$('li').each(function(index, value) {
  // index is what you're looking for
});
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for `each`:

> the callback is passed an array
>   index and a corresponding array value
>   each time.

Note that the index will be zero-based, so if you want your "1, 2, 3..." (from your question), you'll need to make the appropriate accommodations.

Answer (score 3):

Per the jQuery documentation, you can include a callback within the function (as below):

```
$('li').each(function(index, value) { 
  alert('li #' + index); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery passes it as an argument:

```
$('li').each(i, li) {
  // i is the counter (starts at zero)
});
```

<strike>(hold on while I make sure that's the right order; i always get confused b/c "$.map()" is different!)</strike>

yup that's it, index then element.